# changing afp to smb

Tags: 12.04, smb

Since upgrading to 12.04 Nautilus connects to my network drive using AFP. This works some of time but is very slow ans sometimes just crashes Nautilus. I'd like to use smb instead but even though I've now installed Samba I've no idea on how to get Nautilus to use it instead of AFP?

Answer (score 0):

Why not, from your desktop (all apps minimised) click in the top left, I think its laballed Ubuntu Desktop. In the menu up there is "connect to server"

from here you can choose which protocol to use to connect

Comment: Thanks stueng. This worked second time. I selected 'Windows Share'  and put in the IP address of the server. The first time it didn't work, but after trying a SHH connection and going back to 'Windows Share' it worked. Great. I then used CTRL+L in Nautilus and saw it was using a SMB  connection. Lets hope this works more reliability.